# Maintain order of deployment between multiple cloudformation stacks in Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am trying to deploy multiple infra cloud formations through Jenkins and in one of the situations, there are two stacks in which one of the stacks is having a dependency on the other stack. As the deployment script will not be able to maintain the order. So how can I achieve it here in cloud formation

PS: Is there any way that the dependent stack will wait until the other stack got deployed. Here Jenkins can deploy multiple stacks in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html) resource type itself?

> The `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack` type nests a stack as a resource in a
> top-level template.

You can use that along with things like a [WaitCondition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-waitcondition.html) or a [DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute to ensure that one resource is created before another, so you could have a parent Stack that creates two [nested Stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html), where one depends on the other.